# Javascript parse Date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to output date in my javascript function. The string passed in is "2018-04-01 12:45:34" and am trying to set a DevExpress DateEdit control's value in Javascript as

```
function setDate(_dateString) {
dtStartTime.SetValue(new Date(_dateString));
}
```

The above line is outputting date as Nann-Na-Na...

Should I be specifying a format?

Thanks
NH

Comment: `new Date('2018-04-01 12:45:34')` seems to work for me.  What are you getting?    Are you sure the parsing is the problem, and not setting the value?

Comment: Parsing of non–standard strings is implementation dependent.